# How to add field within nested JSON when reading from/writing to Kafka via a Spark dataframe

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I've a Spark (v.3.0.1) job written in Java that reads Json from Kafka, does some transformation and then writes it back to Kafka. For now, the incoming message structure in Kafka is something like:
`{"catKey": 1}`. The output from the Spark job that's written back to Kafka is something like: `{"catKey":1,"catVal":"category-1"}`. The code for processing input data from Kafka goes something as follows:

```
DataFrameReader dfr = putSrcProps(spark.read().format("kafka"));

for (String key : srcProps.stringPropertyNames()) {
  dfr = dfr.option(key, srcProps.getProperty(key));
}

Dataset<Row> df = dfr.option("group.id", getConsumerGroupId())
                     .load()
                     .selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as value")
                     .withColumn("jsonData", from_json(col("value"), schemaHandler.getSchema()))
                     .select("jsonData.*");

// transform df

df.toJSON().write().format("kafka").option("key", "val").save()
```

I want to change the message structure in Kafka. Now, it should be of the format: `{"metadata": <whatever>, "payload": {"catKey": 1}}`. While reading, we need to read only the contents of the payload, so the dataframe remains similar. Also, while writing back to Kafka, first I need to wrap the msg in payload, add a metadata. The output will have to be of the format: `{"metadata": <whatever>, "payload": {"catKey":1,"catVal":"category-1"}}`. I've tried manipulating the contents of the `selectExpr` and `from_json` method, but no luck so far. Any pointer on how to achieve the functionality would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the content of payload in your JSON you can use `get_json_object`. And to create the new output you can use the built-in functions `struct` and `to_json`.

Given a Dataframe:

```scala
val df = Seq(("""{"metadata": "whatever", "payload": {"catKey": 1}}""")).toDF("value").as[String]

df.show(false)
+--------------------------------------------------+
|value                                             |
+--------------------------------------------------+
|{"metadata": "whatever", "payload": {"catKey": 1}}|
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Then creating the new column called "value"

```scala
val df2 = df
  .withColumn("catVal", lit("category-1")) // whatever your logic is to fill this column
  .withColumn("payload",
      struct(
        get_json_object(col("value"), "$.payload.catKey").as("catKey"),
        col("catVal").as("catVal")
      )
  )
  .withColumn("metadata",
        get_json_object(col("value"), "$.metadata"),
  ).select("metadata", "payload")

df2.show(false)
+--------+---------------+
|metadata|payload        |
+--------+---------------+
|whatever|[1, category-1]|
+--------+---------------+

val df3 = df2.select(to_json(struct(col("metadata"), col("payload"))).as("value"))
df3.show(false)
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|value                                                                 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"metadata":"whatever","payload":{"catKey":"1","catVal":"category-1"}}|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time to post a solution. There's a catch though. I need the value for payload to be a json object not a string. I'm also trying to derive a solution. Will update the post if I can get it to work.

Comment: @Bitswazsky, have edited my answer and the payload is now an JSON object rather then a String.

Comment: In case, the payload has variable number of arbitrary k-v pairs, is it possible to traverse through all of those using any form of iterator within the `withcolumn()`?

Comment: You could try `$.payload.*`.